# DirectX - How to disable the viewport transform

Tags: directx, viewport, directx-11

Is there a way to completely disable the viewport transform in DirectX 11 or at least define a custom ScreenSpace-to-PixelSpace transformation?

P.S.:

I have read that in older DX versions there used to be things like

```
pDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_VIEWPORTENABLE, FALSE );
```

but I could not find any info on that no MSDN.

*Background:*

*I have a physical camera and I know the view matrix of this camera and a projection matrix which transforms all the way from view space to pixel space.
Now I want to simulate the camera image by simply reusing those same matrices in DirectX.*

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve, but maybe this question has some starting points for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583380/what-is-the-xbox360s-d3drs-viewportenable-equivalent-on-winxp-d3d9

Answer (score -1):

There's no things like:

```
pDevice->SetRenderState( D3DRS_VIEWPORTENABLE, FALSE );
```

But, viewport-transform can be represent as a matrix. Let's call it V.
Append matrix inverse( V ) to your transform-pipeline. 
this will 'cancel' viewport-transform.
e.g.

```
(model-to-world) * (world-to-view) * (projection) * inverse(V)
```